# Determining length of line that runs along polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, parcel, boundary-length

I am new to QGIS and I am trying to determine how to get the length of street centerlines that run in front of multiple parcel polygons in a county using QGIS. The lines and parcels do not intersect, so I can't use an intersection or clip tool. I tried to buffer the street centerline with the idea that if the centerline polygon intersects the parcel, then I can perform an 'erase' between the 2 polygons, but this leaves me with just another polygon.

I have a rough sketch below. I Would like to know the length (highlighted) of the centerline (green line), that runs along polygons (red) 1,2,3,4..etc.

[image: rough sketch]

Comment: What projection your data are? And maybe add the version of `QGIS` you are using (not very imprortant but in this way your question is more _solid_, if that makes sense)

Comment: @Nikos thanks for your response. My QGIS version is 3.2815 and my projection is in state plane US Feet

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. Comments are meant for ask for clarifications, not for providing them.

Answer (score 0):

Using QGIS 3.28.15,

You can create `Polygon centroids` (it's a SAGA tool), then you can run the `Points to path` tool to connect the centroids and lastly, in the attribute table of the path layer you can create a new field and calculate the length like so:
[image: attr table]
(make sure you make the layer editable).

I'm sure there is an easiest way to do it, but that's one approach I guess.

My initial polygon layer is in meters.

Comment: thanks again for this. I tried this method and when i ran the path to line tool, I ended up with lines that were not straight, and it appeared zig zaggy. I did some more lookup and I ran the following steps on  a small batch of my polygons  Ran a tool called "Snap Geometries to layer using my centerline as input and polygon as reference. I set a tolerance. This gave me a line output that was not completely snapped to the polygon. I but a little buffer on the polygon, and then ran the intersect tool to get lines within the polygon. Added a new field to this output to measure the length. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ran a tool called "Snap Geometries to layer using my centerline as input and polygon as reference. I set a tolerance. This gave me a line output that was not completely snapped to the polygon. I but a little buffer on the polygon, and then ran the intersect tool to get lines within the polygon. Added a new field to this output to measure the length